# Como comprobar que un String esta vacio

Tags: java

Tengo una clase para cargar un servicio, ingreso a la clase a traves de un panel que es el menu principal de un programa. Lo que yo quiero es que cuando le pregunto un nombre del servicio a agregar a la persona, y esta no ingresa ningun nombre, vuelva al menu principal, pero en ves de eso me muestra la siguiente ventana que seria ingresar el precio de ese servicio.
Se supone que con la primera condicion if(descripcion == null){retunr;} /* deberia de no entrar a la parte de preguntarme el precio.

```
public static void cargarServicio(ArrayList<Servicio> servicios) {

   
    int codigoIdent = servicios.size() + 1;

    String descripcion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del servicio:");

        if (descripcion == null) { // se presionó el botón cancelar
            return; // salimos de la función sin agregar un nuevo servicio
        
    }

    int importe = 0;
    while (true) {
        String importeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el importe/precio:");
        if (importeString == null) { // se presionó el botón cancelar
            return; // salimos de la función sin agregar un nuevo servicio
        }
        try {
            importe = Integer.parseInt(importeString);
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El importe debe ser un número entero. Intente 
        nuevamente.");
        }
    }

    Servicio servicio = new Servicio(codigoIdent, descripcion, importe);
    servicios.add(servicio);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Servicio agregado: " + servicio);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque el valor no es nulo, es un string vacío. Utiliza `isEmpty()`

```
descripcion.isEmpty()
```

Comment: Gracias Rene. Funciono

Comment: Me parece recordar que si se selecciona la opcion de 'Cancelar' en ese componente, el `JOptionPane` si regresa `null`, por lo que lo correcto seria (Si realmente regresa `null` cuando se cancela) `if (descripcion == null || descripcion.isEmpty()) {}`. Lo menciono como posible causa de `NullPointerException`s imprevistas.

Comment: También puedes usar `isBlank()` para checar si hay espacios o saltos de línea. 
Te agrego documentación para que veas más métodos de Strings [Class StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Comment: Si el valor es `null` debería de funcionar igual, ambos métodos regresan `true` en ese caso, pero nunca está de más checar y agregar las validaciones correspondientes.

Comment: @JettoMartínez Me funcion usando ambos, ==null para el decidir que hacer si precionan cancelar, y is.Empty() para decidir que pasa si precionan OK estando vacio la Input

Comment: @GIAN TOMAS LACEY, si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como aceptada, gracias!.